# Exception while typing into search bar on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm taking over some code since another dev has moved on and his search bar has an error.  I've searched the other threads for help on this, but none of them seem to be my error.  Here is a screen shot of mine and the code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5UrZ.jpg

2014-09-17 11:25:34.665 Moca[11388:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key itemName.'

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    return [searchResults count];

} else {
     return [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] count];
}
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return 71;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"UITableViewCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
//there are two tableviews involved here - one is the main one, and one is associated with searchDisplayController
//self.tableView is set automatically between the main one and the search one.

// Configure the cell...
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


NSArray *items = [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems];
BNRItem *item = nil;


if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    item = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    item = items[indexPath.row];

}

if ([item.subcategory isEqual:@"Urgent"]) {
    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Urgent.png"];
}
else if ([item.subcategory isEqual:@"Emergency"]) {
    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Emergency.png"];
}
else if ([item.subcategory isEqual:@"Standard"]) {
    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Standard.png"];
}
else if ([item.subcategory isEqual:@"Normal"]) {
    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Normal.png"];
}
else {
    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Informational.png"];

}
cell.textLabel.text = item.changeOrder;
cell.detailTextLabel.text =item.title;
return cell;
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
NSArray *items = [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems];
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"itemName contains[c] %@", searchText];
searchResults = [items filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                 selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

return YES;
}
```

EDIT add item details

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BDDetailedChange : NSObject


+ (instancetype)randomItem;

- (instancetype)initWithItemName:(NSString *)name
              valueInDollars:(NSString *)value
                serialNumber:(NSString *)sNumber;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *itemName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *serialNumber;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *valueInDollars;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSDate *dateCreated;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subcategory; //Emergency
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *service; 
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *associatedCIs; 
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *environment;//    Production
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *approvalGroup;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *initiator;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *coordinator;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *riskLevel;//  Low
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *performingGroup;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *implementationPlan;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *validationPlan;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *recoveryScope;


@end
```

BNR item .h

```
@interface BNRItem : NSObject

{

 NSString *_approverEid;
 NSString *_assignmentGroup;
 NSString *_changeOrder;
 NSString *_subcategory; //Emergency
 NSString *_title; //title
}

- (void)setApproverEid: ( NSString *)aEid;
- (NSString*)approverEid;

- (void)setAssignmentGroup: ( NSString *)aGrp;
- (NSString*)assignmentGroup;

- (void)setChangeOrder: ( NSString *)co;
- (NSString*)changeOrder;

- (void)setSubcategory: ( NSString *)sub;
- (NSString*)subcategory;

- (void)setTitle: ( NSString *)title;
- (NSString*)title;

@end
```

BNRItem.m

```
#import "BNRItem.h"


@implementation BNRItem

- (void)setApproverEid:(NSString *)aEid
{
_approverEid = aEid;

}

- (void)setAssignmentGroup: ( NSString *)aGrp
{
_assignmentGroup = aGrp;
}

- (void)setChangeOrder: ( NSString *)co
{
    _changeOrder=co;
}

- (void)setSubcategory: ( NSString *)sub
{
_subcategory= sub;
}

- (void)setTitle: ( NSString *)title
{
_title = title;
}


- (NSString*)approverEid
{
return _approverEid;
}

- (NSString*)assignmentGroup
{
return _assignmentGroup;
}


- (NSString*)changeOrder
{
return _changeOrder;
}


- (NSString*)subcategory
{
return _subcategory;
}


- (NSString*)title
{
return _title;
}

@end
```

Comment: Your predicate doesn't seem to be working. What kind of object are in `searchResults`? Does it have a `itemName` property?

Comment: I added my details for items.  itemName is in there.

Comment: That error message usually means that there's a mismatch between a class in your xib or storyboard and the matching class in code.  First try a complete clean and delete derived data in case Xcode is confused.  Assuming that doesn't work, find where `itemName` is mentioned in your xib/storyboard and make sure the right class is specified for its connection.

Comment: Where would itemName be stored on the storyboard piece?  I went through the attributes on the pane on the right and didn't see a spot.

Comment: What is inside BNRItem? Is it possible you are mixing up BNRItem with BDDetailedChange? Looks like `items` contains items of BNRItems not BDRDetailedChange's.

Comment: I added my BNRItems, it looks like itemName isn't in there.  Do I need to point to a field there, or change the search pointer to bddetailedchange?